# Unity3D Collision on Demand

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I'm working on a title where a player can drop a bomb on his current position. The problem is that I whish, that the player cannot walk through any placed bomb (except he took up an specific item).

But a non-trigger collider causes, that placing the bomb pushes the player away (maybe into a wall, where he finally stuck), which seems not to be the way.

So is there any easy way to enable the collision with the bomb, which stops player movement script-based or do I have to check on each step the player takes, if he would collide with a bomb and stop the movement?

**Update (Answer to Comment from Programmer)**

If the bomb collider is not meant as a trigger, which would cause the auto collision behaviour, the player who drops the bomb as his current position, is pushed away in any direction, which is event not the wished behaviour, because the player can also pushed into a wall, where he cannot get out.

**Update (after Answer from Jeroen De Clercq)**

The bomb collider is initially set to trigger and the attached script looks like this:

```
public class Bomb : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SphereCollider collider;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        collider = GetComponent<SphereCollider>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Collider[] collidings = Physics.OverlapSphere(gameObject.transform.position, 1);
        if (!collidings.Any(s => s.tag.Equals("Player")))
            collider.isTrigger = false;
    }
}
```

And if the player collected an item which allows him to walk through the bomb, his own layer will be changed to a specified player layer, which does not collide with the bomb!

Comment: Guess you can use layers to which layer will be have an interaction with which layer , you can read more [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) at Unity Docs.

Comment: *"But a non-trigger collider causes, that placing the bomb pushes the player away (maybe into a wall, where he finally stuck), which seems not to be the way."* Please explain what you mean by this. You need non trigger collider to prevent collision otherwise you would have to write some crazy looking code.

Comment: @EmreE: Thanks for the link, but layers seems not to be the right way, because basically I want players to collide to bombs, but not when they place them

Comment: @Programmer: Tried to explain it better in post update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Soon as u Spawn the bomb; spawn a invisible gameobject with a script and inactive collider on it that. Make the script check if anyone is in the collider, as soon as he is out activate the collider. make sure it is a child of the bomb that way they die together. As for your special item, just add method to same script that been called to deactivate the collider and that overides the checking for player aswell.

Comment: Sounds great, I will try that out and give you a feedback as soon as possible